# Real time clocking out system

Tags: python

I have a file that I want to filter words from, however I have tried using a code that I found but it did not change anything. I have coded it so that it opens the file and displays the content within it. I just need assistance with filtering words that are within the file.

As an output I want the list of words in new text file as :

clock in

clock in

clock in

clock in

I am still relatively new to this so be kind.

Comment: First set variable to open file and read mode then you have to make another variable to user input to find specific string then use if else condition for Example: if user input == file or you can use for loop too

Comment: It would be best if you showed your code and the contents of the input file.